# findFundamentalMat returns 9x3 matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I use OpenCV 2.4.5. When I use `findFundamentalMat` with method `FM_7POINT` I get `9x3` matrix in result. But when I use `findFundamentalMat` with any other method and with only `7 points` in images (in order to use 7-point method) I get `3x3` matrix. What's wrong? Should I get `3x3` matrix anytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat) for `findFundamentalMat()` function:

> Normally just one matrix is found. But in case of the 7-point algorithm, the function may return up to 3 solutions (9x3 matrix that stores all 3 matrices sequentially).

The results you get are thus perfectly normal!

Comment: Do you know how can I choose one out of the three potential Fundamental matrices to be used for getting Essential Matrix and then Rotation matrix and translation vector?